# OLD School asp.net page is taking large amount of time to complete the submit

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

We are running into a IE9 issue with old asp.net (VB) page and we are not sure what is happening and we are hoping someone can make some suggestions here

- We have this .aspx page with pretty light controls and a button with a runat server

  ```
  <div class="TopMargin">
      <button id="btnAddTemplate" runat="server"><asp:Image ID="imgAddTemplate"  SkinID="add" Height="12" Width="12" runat="server" /> Add New Template</button>
  </div>
  ```

The Submit trigger a post back and we have a serverclick event attached to the button which just does a response .redirect

Between The Click and the Hitting the Page_Load in the code behind the page is getting stuck somewhere and it takes almost 90 sec to reach to page load from The Form submit on post back..

This happens only on IE9 and IE10 Chrome and firefox are fine.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: I have also tried enabling the .net tracing but none of the aspx page events from begin to Render are showing to take lot of time. everything happens in like 0.33 secs. I have also tried by redirecting  the submit to the same page to compare the trace logs but still it shows nothing...something is happening in client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well got a solution but not sure why the other one is not working. if someone can help in explaining it that will be great

Replaced the

```
<button id="abc" runat="server"><asp:Image ID="imgAddTemplate"  SkinID="add" Height="12" Width="12" runat="server" /> Add New Template</button>
```

with the input type Button as

```
<input type="button" id ="abc" value="Add New Template" runat="server" />
```